# How to set automatically a reminder depending on meeting time

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, office365, meetings

I don't know how many of you have the same problem, but I work in a company where most of the colleagues wake up considerably earlier than I do.

This led in the past to me missing by 30-40 minutes a meeting early in the morning because I didn't know it was there - and the reminder was set to 15 mins only.

Anyway, in the concrete examples, **I'd like to automatically set a reminder to 1 hour before every meeting starting before 9:30**.

Is there a smart way to do it? With or without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your default meeting time:

1. Click the **File** tab.
2. Click **Options**.
3. Click **Calendar**.
4. Under **Calendar options**, next to **Default reminders**, click a new time.
5. Click **OK**.

[From Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-reminder-time-58414862-1a3a-4344-ad15-a5f14a750e95)

If you wanted to modify existing meetings with VBA you could loop through all meetings and modify the [MeetingItem.ReminderTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.remindertime) property.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook default meeting time should only be used to all the meeting items and cannot be used for customization of a single part.

Found a similar VBA thread here, for your reference: [How to Auto Set Different Reminder Time for Outlook Meetings in Different Color Categories](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-set-different-reminder-time-outlook-meetings-different-color-categories/)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.